# Laravel Chunk to show thousands records of data?

Tags: php, laravel, chunks

I want to show almost a hundred records from the database. But the process very slow. So I try to add a chunk in the blade

Here is my controller

```
 $user= User::where('status', '>=', '2')->get();
```

Here is my view.blade.php

```
@foreach($user->chunk(100) as $chunk)
      @foreach ($chunk as $data)
           <tr> 
               <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
               <td>xxxx<td>
           <tr>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But I didn't find the difference between before and after-use chunks. I know I can use data tables serverside/vajra/larawire. I also try with paginating but the searching/sort function not working coz I use data tables.

Since this website already lives. is there any short-term solution for that? because I have planning to implementation the serverside for the permanent fix but can do it asap.

if I chunk like this in the controller

```
 $user= User::select('status','date','id','name','xxx')->where('status', '>=', '2')->orderBy('date_assign_fa','DESC')
->chunk(50, function($user) {
    foreach ($users $user) {
        **what i put in here if in im blade i also have foreach?**
    }
});
```

Comment: First thing you should try is limiting selected columns as I am sure you don't need data from all the columns

Comment: You are chunking collection not actual SQL request. This will only decrease your performance. Correct chunking: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: from the doc that i understand its only for update,delete,or insert. how about if i want to select and show the records?. please refer my updated question. how to implementation the chunk in my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out that you are using relationship in this case:
You should be using eager loading:

```
$user = User::with('Detail')->where('status', '>=', '2')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Also you can do something like this to receive speficic columns from relationship:

```
$user = User::with([
    'Detail' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('column1', 'column2');
    }
])->where('status', '>=', '2')->get();
```

This could be single solution to all the performance issues

**Old answer**

As arrays are less heavy then collections one thing you could try is:

```
$usersArray = [];

User::select('status','date','id','name','xxx')
    ->where('status', '>=', '2')->orderBy('date_assign_fa','DESC')
    ->chunk(100, function($users) use ($usersArray) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $usersArray[] = $user;
        }
    });
```

And then loop `$usersArray` in your view.

Also it could be simpler / faster to just use raw query:

```
$users = DB::select(
    "SELECT
        status, date, id, name, xxx
    FROM users
    WHERE status >= 2
    ORDER BY date_assign_fa DESC"
);
```

As this will return you array not collection and this should use less memory / processor

Comment: How many users do you have if it is slowing your site so much?

Comment: hi tq for ur help, if in blade i only show details from table User, its work. but how about if i have relationship with other table. previously i use {{$user->Detail->address}}. but since use array i use {{$user['status']}}. the records more than 4000

Comment: if i use with->(Detail) i will get error SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

Comment: @ezles88 Then one option would be to combine it with chunking results and another would be to use `join` in a raw query

Comment: @ezles88 Did you test chunking request? Using `with(...)` creates query that uses `whereIn('user_id', [...])` and if you have more users than parameter limit then you get error. Chunking should solve this